# "Theory" question on system of first order linear equations, help?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $x_1 =y$ and $x_2 = y'$

then the second order equation
$$y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y =0$$ corresponds to the system $x_1'=x_2$ and $x_2' = -q(t)x_1 -p(t)x_2$.

Show that if $x^{(1)}$ and $x^{(2)}$ are a fundamental set of solutions of Eq: $x_2'=-q(t)x_1 -p(t)x_2$. (this is the same equation as above) and if $y^{(1)}$ and $y^{(2)}$ are a fundamental set of solutions of eq: $y''+ p(t)y' +q(t)y =0$ then $W[y^{(1)} , y^{(2)}] = cW[x^{(1)} , x^{(2)}]$ where $c$ is a nonzero constant.

Hint: $y^{(1)} (t)$ and $y^{(2)} (t)$ must be linear combinations of $x_{11}(t)$ and $x_{12}(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_1=y$ and $x_2=y'\implies x_2'=y''$, then 
\begin{align}
x_2'&=-qx_1-px_2\tag{1}\\
x_2'+qx_1+px_2&=0\\
y''+qy+py'&=0\\
y''+py'+qy&=0\tag{2}.
\end{align}

The superscript notation is hideous to type, so allow me to rename some things. The result you need is:

> **If $\{f,g\}$ forms a fundamental solution set (FSS) of $(1)$ and $\{y_1,y_2\}$ forms a FSS of $(2)$, then $W[f,g]=cW[y_1,y_2]$, for $c\not=0$.**

To see this, since the FSS are for equivalent DEs, we can write
$$
f=c_1y_1+c_2y_2, \quad g=d_1y_1+d_2y_2, \quad\text{ for some }c_i,d_i.
$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
W[f,g]&=fg'-gf'\\
&=(c_1y_1+c_2y_2)(d_1y_1+d_2y_2)'-(d_1y_1+d_2y_2)(c_1y_1+c_2y_2)'\\
&\vdots\\
&=(c_1d_2-c_2d_1)y_1y_2'+(c_2d_1-c_1d_2)y_2y_1'\\
&=[c_1d_2-c_2d_1](y_1y_2'-y_2y_1')\\
&=c\cdot W[y_1,y_2],
\end{align*}
with $$c=c_1d_2-c_2d_1.$$

Note that $c\not=0$ since otherwise we get $W[f,g]=0$, but we know $\{f,g\}$ is a FSS, so the Wronskian of $f$ and $g$ does not vanish.

Comment: thanks man, and I have no idea what x_11 and x_12 means, this book is just awful.